# How to install ui-grid in angular-wakanda?

Tags: wakanda

There are  at least 3 options that I can discern:
1.  - npm Module
2.  - Bower component
3.  - copy ui-grid files to the widget folder provided by Wakanda.

Num 3 is my best guess and preferred method.

If it is #3, what files need to go into the widget folder outside of the obvious ui-grid.js and ui-grid.css?

Answer (score 2):

ui-grid.js and ui-grid.css installed inside Projectfolder: Quickstart/web/widgets/ along with the entire ui-grid file set.

Angular-wakanda is accessing the files.

Comment: No entity.collection data displayed in the grid. Data has had $transform operation and displays in ng-repeat.